# unknown column mysql where clause - but I can access and set it within my app. what is causing this?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

models:

```
   class Change < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessor :selected_end_index, :selected_start_index, :revision_number
```

error:

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'revision_number' in 'where clause': SELECT * FROM `changes` WHERE (kind = 2 && status = -1 && content_id = 2 && revision_number = 0)  ORDER BY id DESC
```

method:

```
  def new_change_requests_for_latest_version
    changes = Change.find(:all, 
                :conditions => ["kind = ? && status = ? && content_id = ? && revision_number = ?", 
                                Change::CHANGE, Change::NEW, self[:id], self.current_version],
                :order => "id DESC")

    return changes
  end
```

Comment: Are both the working and non-working events happening in the same environment, or is one test and the other dev? Also, idiomatic Ruby suggestion -- no need to store your changes and return them one line later. Just return Change.find(:all)... (And the return keyword is optional.)

Comment: As it turns out, I forgot to migrate my test db </embarassment>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means there is no column named "revision_number".  The reason you can access it in your app is because  attr_accessor sets up the field in the in-memory object.  But any value assigned to it will not be persisted in the database, nor can you query on it.